# How to set array to default like definited?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

how can i reset array to default? I have some functions that's modifying array and i want to set it like in Dim after click reset button.

```
Dim array() As String = {"H", "C", "N", "O", "Na", "Cl", "Fe", "Mg", "Cu", "Ag", "Au", "Pt", "K", "Pb", "Ca", "S", "P", "Al", "Si", "Zn", "Sn", "I"}

Private Sub reset_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles reset.Click
   array() = {"H", "C", "N", "O", "Na", "Cl", "Fe", "Mg", "Cu", "Ag", "Au", "Pt", "K", "Pb", "Ca", "S", "P", "Al", "Si", "Zn", "Sn", "I"} 
' it's not working
End Sub
```

Comment: Please pay attention to the information the IDE provides you in cases like this.  it tells you what is wrong. *it's not working* is a horrible problem description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lose the parentheses:

```
   array = {"H", "C", "N", "O", "Na", "Cl", "Fe", "Mg", "Cu", "Ag", "Au", "Pt", "K", "Pb", "Ca", "S", "P", "Al", "Si", "Zn", "Sn", "I"}
```

Comment: Before it didnt work for me, but now perfect. Thanks!